# SSL certificate issue in intellij with gradle

Tags: ssl, gradle, intellij-idea

I have a gradle-managed project which I have been working on for the last few years. The code is published to an artifactory instance, which was migrated, company-wide, to AWS recently.

Ever since then I have been facing the following issue whenever I try to do a gradle sync for the project, rendering development impossible:

javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Certificate for artifactory.domain.us doesn't match any of the subject alternative names: [*.domain.space]

I have tried the following:

Updating the intellij IDE to the latest version

Using local gradle distribution instead of built in wrapper (latest version)

Updating my jdk from 8 to 10 and then going back to 8

Copying the certificate of artifactory.domain.us from the browser to the jre's cacerts keystore using the keytool

Enabling and disabling various JVM and gradle VM related to tls and ssl ignore

Since no other developer in my team is facing this issue, it is probably a bad configuration from my end, but I can't figure out what. Please help!

Comment: Somewhere you told intellij to connect to `example.com` over SSL, but when it tries to make that connection it gets a certificate that doesn't say it's for `example.com`. Perhaps you have configured intellij to connect to an IP address instead of a domain name?

Comment: Perhaps you're right, but I can't figure out where! Proxy settings? VM options? There are no SSL-related settings AFAICS.

Comment: Well, you can specify repositories with something like `https://10.1.2.3/myrepo` once and intellij will remember it. Try looking in the log files.